# why this question marked as off topic

Tags: discussion

[How to show time in Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357266/how-to-show-time-in-ubuntu-13-10)
I want some body why they mark that question as OFF-Topic ? I want to a bit description. I use the answer and his suggestion work for me :-| bug!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it was a bug report. This isn't always clear-cut and how best to handle them can vary hugely depending on what's already been done. In this case it turns out there was already a duplicate. It should have been closed against that (I've fixed that now).

If you'd like to know more, [there are a few discussions on the topic of bug reports](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bug-reports).

Comment: Perhaps consider a merge, the dupe has more views than the original!

Comment: @JorgeCastro That's not what I see (the master has ~5k more) and besides, we'd just be merging in a load of duplicate answers and it'd nuke the dupe (which is otherwise casting its own SEO net). There's nothing to gain from it.